Why A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_inappwebview' and Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.L
i want to run my app but i get error:
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_inappwebview'.

Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

and i was tried to make same changes in may manifest.xml:

and this is my build.gradle:
    plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.resident_hotel_app_therese"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

      versionName = flutter.versionName
    }
}
}

